# how to import graph in a python module

Tags: python

I am a newbie in python but I got a code in python that I got to run it

```
from graph import Graph, Task
```

in this line, I have an error saying

> No module named 'graph'

how can I fix this?
thanks for your time and effort

Comment: As the error says the module `graph` is missing.
Is it a local module?

Comment: The code you have found uses a module called graph. Perhaps there is a file or folder called graph in the same repository? If so you would need to save it in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be because it is a typo as per my knowledge, the right name of the module is 'graphs' or 'graphviz' and not 'graph'

or may be you have not installed the module

you have to install module 'graph' on your system using 'pip' through cmd